# Singleton property access in objective C

Tags: objective-c, properties, singleton

I'm using a standard, modern singleton class with a singleton holding a CTFontRef, like so:

```
@interface MySingleton : NSObject {
    CTFontRef paintingFont;
}

@property (readonly) CTFontRef paintingFont;

@end


@implementation MySingleton

+ (MySingleton*)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static MySingleton *sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];

        //NB
        sharedInstance->paintingFont = 
           CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("Helvetica"), 80.0, nil);   
    });
   return sharedInstance;
}

@end
```

Then elsewhere I call `[[MySingleton sharedinstance] paintingFont]`.

However, this call returns `nil` until I insert an underscore before `paintingFont` like so:

```
        sharedInstance->_paintingFont = 
           CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("Helvetica"), 80.0, nil);
```

Why is this?  Shouldn't the compiler require me to include the underscore?  If not what is the  purpose of the earlier version?  And where did this underscore come in?  I never declared the property with an underscore to begin with, I just see these seemingly random insertions of them into variable names in the debugger window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Xcode 4.4, when you declare a `@property`, the compiler will automatically create an ivar for you and `@synthesize` the accessor methods. The default ivar is one with an underscore.

Using the `->` syntax you access ivars directly and not the property. So, in your `sharedInstance` method you set your own ivar (without the underscore). However when you later try to access it, you use the `[ ]` which will use the automatically synthesized getter method to access your property (and the automatically generated ivar with an underscore).

You should use the `.` notation instead of the `->` to access the property. Or simply use the automatically generated ivar called `_paintingFont`.

You can also make a property readwrite in your implementation file by adding the code below. This will allow you to use the dot syntax in your implementation to set the property, but still leave it readonly for other classes.

```
@interface MySingleton ()
@property (readwrite) CTFontRef paintingFont;
@end
```

If you want a different ivar, you can use `@synthesize` to override it. In both cases, you don't have to declare an ivar anymore.

```
@implementation MySingleton
@synthesize paintingFont;
....
@end
```

Comment: Okay I see.  I would add to this a few more observations.  First, that as written above under both 'versions' there are inadvertently two distinct ivars being created: paintingFont and _paintingFont.  This is confusing and unintended and it initially felt 'scary' to me from the point of view that you couldn't determine such without looking at the interface file.  On the other hand, the programmer error can be entirely localized to the implementation code since an explicit @synthesize statement would fix the problem.

Comment: #2: more important, the reason for the underscore business in the first place (something I tried to get at in my original question) is it was introduced in order to prevent a certain kind of bug where you unintentionally change a property outside of its setter function and therefore miss out on the important side effects that may take place in that setter.  The Big Nerd Ranch people have this issue covered here: http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/463-a-motivation-for-ivar-decorations/

Comment: That might be the reason, yes, to better differentiate ivars and properties. I just explained where the underscore came from, technically. Btw, this was never really a bug. It's just a matter of knowing what you do. There are situations where you might want to access the ivar directly.

Answer (score 2):

This is because in declaring a property paintingFont the Obj C compiler creates an instance variable _paintingFont.

In general the setting of a property/variable can either be done by

1. The instance as in your solution `sharedInstance->_paintingFont = ...`
2. Using the property and . notation `sharedInstance.paintingFont = ...`. This calls the generated method setPaintingFont which then assigns to the instance variable.

However in this case the property is readonly so method 2 cannot be used.

Comment: @Merk See my post about how you can make a property readwrite only inside your implementation, but not for others.

Comment: @DrummerB - yes but ugh I prefer the ivar way, as a) that declaration will get miscopied b) I look at the interface to see what variables are and if they differ in the implementation...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a). And you still can go with ivars and properties, but then you have to use @synthesize too. Just as before the whole automation came up.