# Singleton pattern in Objective-C using a class property

Tags: objective-c, properties, singleton

I'm trying to create a singleton class in Objective-C that will also be consumed in Swift. I'd like the singleton instance to be accessible in Swift as a property.

It appears that Apple does something similar (though not quite a singleton) in `NSFileManager`.

```
@property(class, readonly, strong) NSFileManager *defaultManager;
```

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1409234-defaultmanager

Here's my (simplified) attempt so far:

FOOMyManager.h:

```
@interface FOOMyManager : NSObject

@property(class, readonly, strong) FOOMyManager *defaultManager;

- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;

@end
```

FOOMyManager.mm

```
@implementation FOOMyManager

+ (FOOMyManager *)defaultManager {
    static dispatch_once_t s_once = 0;
    static FOOMyManager *s_instance = nil;
    dispatch_once(&s_once, ^{
        s_instance = [[FOOMyManager alloc] initForDefaultManager];
    });

    return s_instance;
}

- (instancetype)initForDefaultManager {
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

@end
```

I've seen instances of a similar pattern being used to create singletons using

```
+ (instancetype)defaultManager;
```

But I'd explicitly like to try and use properties if possible. Is my attempt the "right" way to do this?

Comment: There are many similar queastions already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381085/how-to-create-singleton-class-in-objective-c, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319731/objective-c-singleton-implementation, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568935/how-do-i-implement-an-objective-c-singleton-that-is-compatible-with-arc, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-should-my-objective-c-singleton-look-like, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208041/what-is-the-use-of-singleton-class-in-objective-c.

Comment: Also, apart from `init` don't forget to make `new` `NS_UNAVAILABLE`, too.

Comment: @lazarevzubov I did look through those. Unfortunately, none of them use @ property for this. I'd like to know if the pattern I'm using with @ property has any downfalls.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I declare class-level properties in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695980/how-do-i-declare-class-level-properties-in-objective-c) Skip the answers before 2016.

Comment: @Willeke I'm afraid not. I know how to create a property, as is the case in my attempt so far. I just don't know if I'm creating the property correctly when implementing the singleton pattern. The fact that I haven't been able to find examples of this and yet Apple seems to be moving in this direction is why I want to double check my approach.

Comment: Apple just changed the interfaces from a getter to a property. `NSFileManager.defaultManager` exists since OS X 10.0. Is the question about the declaration of the property or about the implementation of the singleton?

Comment: @KMehta what about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631705/singleton-property-access-in-objective-c ? does it help?

Comment: Or this https://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/ ?

Comment: @Willeke the question is about implementing the singleton pattern where the singleton reference is exposed as a class property.

Comment: @Andrey neither of those answer the question. They're both about calling a property on a singleton, which is different from accessing the singleton instance as a class property of an interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you've got the right principles.

You don't need the `strong`, since that's an attribute used for a synthesized setter telling it that it should retain a strong reference to anything passed into the setter. In this case it's not doing anything since class properties are never synthesized automatically, and it's marked as `readonly` so `strong` wouldn't have any effect anyways.

Your code looks good. `dispatch_once` is the preferred way of instantiating a singleton.

As far as any improvements, you can add a message to the unavailable attribute: `__attribute__((unavailable("Use FOOMyManager.defaultManager")))`. I wouldn't say it's necessary or adds much since it's clear from the header file what to do, but I'm including it here as an option.